# Why does this address have a balance?

Tags: transactions

I do not understand how this address has a balnce of >$55k at current prices: https://etherscan.io/address/0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

There have been >300 transactions to it, but most with 0 Eth.

Also I am assuming that this isn't a real address because nobody could brute force a private key from it, and it's extremely unlikely that one would just arrive at it.

What gives?

Comment: Check out this transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb20e0f430b421e1185e44c909da473f5133d2c8b5d680f0412b0f5154d0b2b30

Comment: Thank you @Jesbus! I missed it somehow. Any idea about the other part of the question, whether it's a real address in the sense that someone has the private key?

Comment: It's used by a bunch of companies (Bancor, Kyber, etc) as a "place holder" for what is referred to as "Ether Token", in order to allow for Ether to be handled similarly as any other token in the system. It is not supposed to be an address which you transfer your Ethers or Tokens to. Obviously no one has its private key, so if you do choose to transfer your assets to it, then you can rest assure that you will never get to see them again.

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration, that makes sense! How do I accept a comment as solution?

Comment: Not possible, you can thumbs it up I suppose...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's used by a bunch of companies (Bancor, Kyber, etc) as a "placeholder" for what is referred to as "Ether Token", in order to allow for Ether to be handled similarly as any other token in the system.

It is not supposed to be an address which you transfer your Ethers or Tokens to.

Obviously no one has its private key, so if you do choose to transfer your assets to it, then you can rest assure that you will never get to see them again.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other guys said, it's an address used to identify the ETH coin itself as if it was an ERC20 token. Many protocols use ERC20 tokens so when it comes to the main currency in Ethereum, ETH itself, they have to create some kind of representation to use it as a token.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as zero address or null address 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000. That is, it's just a fancy looking address that nobody knows the private key of, and apparently some people use it to burn funds.

The general usage is used for implementing a token transfer with Native ETH and ERC20 functions. For example, there is a function that swaps tokens. In this function, users can choose to swap Ether or ERC20 tokens. Hence, user can choose to input `0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE` or their ERC20 token address that they want to swap.